# How to find a control located inside datalist itemtemplate, on a Page_Load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, listitem

I have a datalist which display's thumbnails of images and a download icon under it, when user clicks on the download icon, system download's the image at client's location.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlSearchDetails" runat="server" OnItemCommand="dtlSearchDetails_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="dtlSearchDetails_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="dtlImageCol" ImageUrl='<%# "~/uploads/thumbnails/" + Eval("ImageName") %>' /><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="dtusage" Text='<%# Eval("usage") %>' Style="color: #CC121B;"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="dtlImgDownload" CommandName="dtlImgDownload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>' ImageUrl="images/download.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;"/>&nbsp;
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
```

All works well just the problem is that datalist is wrapped inside updatepannel and hence in order to download image at user end I need to register the control on the Page_Load event :

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(dtlImgDownload);
```

since the `dtlImgDownload` is inside the datalist, I always get an error `"The name dtlImgDownload doesn't exists in current context."`

I tried several ways to find the control like `dtlSearchDetails.FindControl("dtlImgDownload ")`
but it always returns null.

I also tried

```
if(dtlSearchDetails.FindControl("dtlImgDownload ") != null)
        {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(dtlSearchDetails.FindControl("dtlImgDownload "));
        }
```

But same result, its always null.

Kindly point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to `Bind` the `DataList`. Then after this, you will need to loop through each of the `DataListItems` in the `DataList`

```
foreach ( DataListItem li in dtlSearchDetails.Items )
{
    ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) li.FindControl("dtlImgDownload");
}
```

This will find the control within each `DataListItem`

Comment: Looks like the code is able to find the ImageButton but still not able to able to register it I used like : 
`if (dtlSearchDetails.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataListItem li in dtlSearchDetails.Items)
            {
                ImageButton img = (ImageButton)li.FindControl("dtlImgDownload");
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(img);
                break;
            }
        }`

Comment: Never mind its working looks like some other issue, Thanks a lot Tim for the time.